# How to Unmarshal XML containing dirty HTML in Go

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, go

I have some XML I want to Unmarshal but it contains dirty HTML in a field I don't even care about. I posted an example here: http://play.golang.org/p/caKCAYyXX2

Is there a way I can tell the Decoder to skip or ignore these errors? I tried making a non-strict Decoder described in the docs, but couldn't get any combinations of `AutoClose` or `Entity` values to get this working. I should mention this XML is from a 3rd party that I have no control over and the contents are always variable, I'm not sure compiling a static list of elements to skip would be feasible. Adding `Description` to the struct with the `xml:"-"` tag makes no difference.

I was able to parse this using Python 2.7 so I hope it would be possible in Go - though I'd prefer to use Go for my use-case :) - I am using the Google's AppEngine for this so the solution would have to be in native Go and not rely on external C libraries.

Relevant code:

```
var XMLData = []byte(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <Container>
   <Timestamp>2014-01-15T21:07:07.217Z</Timestamp>
   <Item>
    <Description>
<table  width="100%" border=0 ><tr><td><table width="100%"><tr><td><!-- Begin Description -->
<TABLE cellSpacing=27 cellPadding=0 width="100%"><TBODY><TR><TD vAlign=top><P align=center>
<TABLE cellPadding=15 width="86%" border=1><TBODY><TR><TD><H3><P>
<H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H><H2><H2>


<IMG SRC=http://www.REMOVED.com/simage/j6x516.jpg>
<BR><BR>
<IMG SRC=http://www.REMOVED.com/simage/j6x517.jpg>

    </Description>
   </Item>
  <Container>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`)

type Data struct {
    Timestamp string `xml:"Body>Container>Timestamp"`
}

var o Data
decoder := xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBuffer(XMLData))
decoder.Strict = false
decoder.AutoClose = xml.HTMLAutoClose
decoder.Entity = xml.HTMLEntity
if err := decoder.Decode(&o); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Timestamp: ", o.Timestamp)
}
```

Result:
`Error:  XML syntax error on line 14: expected /> in element`

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at using the `xml.Decoder.DecodeElement` approach? RawToken and Skip look they might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the `xml` package, if you have [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org) installed, you can use [Gokogiri](https://github.com/moovweb/gokogiri) to harness its parsing flexibility in Go.

For example, evaluating using an XPath:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/moovweb/gokogiri"
    "github.com/moovweb/gokogiri/xml"
    "github.com/moovweb/gokogiri/xpath"
)

func main() {
    var XMLData = []byte(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<Container>
<Timestamp>2014-01-15T21:07:07.217Z</Timestamp>
<Item>
    <Description>
<table  width="100%" border=0 ><tr><td><table width="100%"><tr><td><!-- Begin Description -->
<TABLE cellSpacing=27 cellPadding=0 width="100%"><TBODY><TR><TD vAlign=top><P align=center>
<TABLE cellPadding=15 width="86%" border=1><TBODY><TR><TD><H3><P>
<H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H2><H><H2><H2>


<IMG SRC=http://www.REMOVED.com/simage/j6x516.jpg>
<BR><BR>
<IMG SRC=http://www.REMOVED.com/simage/j6x517.jpg>

    </Description>
</Item>
<Container>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`)

    doc, err := gokogiri.ParseXml(XMLData)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("XML document could not be parsed")
        return
    }

    nxpath := xpath.NewXPath(doc.DocPtr())
    nodes, err := nxpath.Evaluate(doc.DocPtr(), xpath.Compile("//Timestamp"))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("XPath could not be evaluated")
        return
    }

    if len(nodes) == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("Elements matching XPath not found")
        return

    }
    timestamp := xml.NewNode(nodes[0], doc).InnerHtml()

    fmt.Printf("%s", timestamp) // "2014-01-15T21:07:07.217Z"
}
```

This works with Go v1.2 on OS X 10.9.1. The Gokogiri package also includes a CSS selector converter, but I've never used it and can't vouch for it.

Comment: Thanks, but I am hosting this on AppEngine and I don't think I'll be able to use libxml2, though this does seem to solve it in a more general use-case. My apologies for not specifying the platform in my question, I'll update it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your decoder code is fine (you can actually remove the `decoder.AutoClose = xml.HTMLAutoClose` line). The problem is that the `img` tags don't have quotes around the `src` attributes. See [this playground](http://play.golang.org/p/FQAL6Qyrki).

Comment: Hmmm, well what can be done about this? I don't have control over the XML so I can't "fix" the sloppy HTML at it's source. Is there a reason other XML decoders are able to finish parsing this but Go's does not?

Comment: I suppose other parsers are less strict. Possible solutions: regex search and replace to fix the img src. Or surround the Description tag with cdata markup.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`go.net/html`](http://code.google.com/p/go.net/html) package — for me, it parsed your sample data just OK.

The problem with this package, as I perceive it, is that it returns to you a hierarchy of "nodes" (one per HTML element) which you're supposed to traverse.  I mean, no unmarshaling to a struct, at least on the first sight.  Thus you might have better luck with something like [`html-query`](https://github.com/hailiang/html-query) or [`goquery`](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) which should allow you to query the parsed DOM using the().so().called().fluent().style()…

[`go-html-transform`](http://code.google.com/p/go-html-transform/) is yet another possible option.

In other words, my key idea is to treat the whole SOAP reply you're dealing with as HTML, not XML because that's what it really is and hope a HTML parser will be able to cope with it thanks to the HTML's more lax formatting rules and consequently more permissive parsers.